# ElectronJS ReferenceError: navigator is not defined

Tags: javascript, electron, custom-titlebar

I'm trying make a custom titlebar on electron. But when i started my app, i take "ReferenceError: navigator is not defined" issue. Please help. This is the code snippet from my main.js

[My Codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpzZo.png)

```
// 1. Require the installed module
const customTitlebar = require('custom-electron-titlebar');
// 2. Create the custom titlebar with your own settings
//    To make it work, we just need to provide the backgroundColor property
//    Other properties are optional.
let MyTitleBar = new customTitlebar.Titlebar({ backgroundColor: customTitlebar.Color.fromHex('#03a9f4')});
```

Comment: lmk where you import this `custom-electron-titlebar`

Comment: in main.js m8 :.

Comment: please use this at your renderer

Comment: your main process is just for managing the renderer process. there is no navigator at main

Answer (score 4):

This can't be executed in [main process](https://www.brainbell.com/javascript/electron-processes.html). 
The main process is for managing the [renderer process](https://www.brainbell.com/javascript/electron-processes.html). There won't be any navigator at Electron main process. And [navigator](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/javascript-tutorial/javascript-window-navigator.php) is property of browser.

The renderer is responsible to render the code to browserWindow. So you can access the navigator of browserWindow at renderer not main.

So please move this to your renderer where you'd like to customize the title bar.

This will be working very well.

Comment: Can we write the actual screenshot api in main, while doing rest of the stuff related to browser related things in renderer. Do you have any example